# How to make my whole project responsive by using both percentages and pixels on css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I need to make html/css/javascript website responsive.

I read a lot about using percentages instead of pixels. But the thing is, I already used 250+ px's in my css. Is there any way to fix this without changing them all into percentages and using the @media query?

Some examples of my code:

```
.main-image {
  height: 100px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}

nav a.admin_page {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  border: none;
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #80af2b;
}
```

As you can see I used a lot of px's for different. Is there any easy way to fix this?

Comment: You don't need to change everything into %, but some things you may want to. You can use css like display flex and grid to help make responsive layouts. You can use chrome dev tools to see how new code can make your html/css responsive, it even has a responsive tool to view your page at various width/heights including mobile device sizes.